# <PDFDownloadLink/> Slowing Down Website In reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf

I want my users to be able to click a button to download a pdf file after they have completed an operation.

But when I put the `<PDFDownloadLink/>` component it slows down the website tremendesouly.

I believe it is because  component is being re rendered several times. But how do I stop it from doing that and still be able to download the pdf?

What am I doing wrong?

here is my code:

```
import { Document, Page, Text, View, StyleSheet, Image, PDFViewer, PDFDownloadLink } from '@react-pdf/renderer';


// Create Document Component
  const MyDocument = () => (
    <Document>
      <Page size="A4" orientation="landscape" style={styles.page}>
          <View style={styles.sectionHead}>
              <Image style={styles.image} src={logo}/>
              <Text style={styles.freightCode}>{freightType}</Text>
              <View style={styles.headDate}>
              </View>
          </View>

          {/*The body section of the pdf*/}
          <View style={styles.sectionInfo}>
              <View style={styles.sectionInfo1}>
              <Text style={styles.sectionInfoHeader}>COLLECTION:</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionInfoText}>{collname}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionInfoText}>{collcompany}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionInfoText}>{colladdress}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionInfoText}>{collphone}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionInfoText}>{collemail}</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.sectionInfo2}>
              <Text style={styles.countryBlock}>{collcountry}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.locationBlock}>{collcity}</Text>
              </View>
          </View>
          {/*The body section of the pdf*/}
          <View style={styles.sectionCodeLocation}>
          <Text style={styles.collDelCode}>{collcountrycode} - {freightType} - {delcountrycode}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.sectionInfo}>
              <View style={styles.sectionInfo1}>
              <Text>DELIVERY:</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionInfoText}>{delname}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionInfoText}>{delcompany}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionInfoText}>{deladdress}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionInfoText}>{delphone}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionInfoText}>{delemail}</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.sectionInfo2}>
              <Text style={styles.countryBlock}>{delcountry}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.locationBlock}>{delcity}</Text>
              
              </View>
          </View>
          {/*The product section of the pdf*/}
          <View style={styles.sectionDetail}>
              <View style={styles.sectionInfo1}>
              <Text style={styles.weightCode}>Weight: {rangeval}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.weightCode}>Content: {shipContent}</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.sectionInfo2}>
              <Text style={styles.weightCode}>Pieces: {pieces}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.weightCode}>Value: {shipValue} BHD</Text>
              </View>
          </View>
          {/*The product section of the pdf*/}
          
          <View style={styles.sectionAWB}>
              <Image style={styles.barcode} src={barcode}/>
          </View>
          {
          <View style={styles.footerDetail}>
          <Text>*Freight DOC* </Text>
          <Text>{getCurrentDate()}</Text>
          </View>}
      </Page>
    </Document>
  );

   return(

             <li><PDFDownloadLink document={<MyDocument/>} fileName="waybill.pdf">{({ blob, url, loading, error }) => (loading ? 'Download Waybill' : 'Download Waybill')}</PDFDownloadLink></li>
      )
```

Comment: Please, show the code which calls the function.

Comment: @OmarDiaa i did, `return ( <PDFDownloadLink document={<MyDocument/>} fileName="waybill.pdf">{({ blob, url, loading, error }) => (loading ? 'Download Waybill' : 'Download Waybill')}</PDFDownloadLink>)`

Comment: @KJ yeah you're right, any solutions to this problem?